# what is a good strategy for a javascript library that supports different variations

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

so i have a library that i want to break up into multiple different variations, with different dependencies... for example, a javascript library using vanilla js, but then a jquery variation, prototype variation, react variation, etc.

the way i imagine how it would work is, for vanilla js, you would just

```
@import 'foolib'
```

but if you wanted the jquery variation...

```
@import 'foolib/jquery'
```

i am open to other approaches, but what is a good approach on architecting something like this? some of the specific questions i have are..

- would they have their own package.json files to declare their own dependencies? or somehow have a core one, with additional package.json for the different variations?
- can all variations live in the same repo? or should they be treated as separate libraries?
- should each variation have it's own semantic version? or all released together under a single version

so just generally looking for thoughts on different strategies, and the pros and cons of each. also, referrals to any library that is attempting to solve the same problem would be helpful

Answer (score 1):

If you have a core library, and several bridge libraries to different frameworks and other libraries, the common solution is to make:

1. Main package
2. One package per bridge/integration

If you for example build a react, and a jQuery version, you don't want to get all React dependencies if you are just a jQuery user. It's better to just get the dependencies you need.

Each package should have it's own version. Your jQuery variant might get a breaking change, which should cause a major version bump, but ideally this should not affect versions of other packages.

Whether they all live in one repository, or if they each have their own repository is more of a matter of taste. For a user that `npm install`s your libraries it's irrelevant. Both approaches are common enough.